# Can I set arbitrary elasticsearch query into Kibana graph?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

alternatively, is there a way to see and edit the queries generated by Kibana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to see the queries generated by Kibana, you should set the option "Inspect" when you configure your histogram.

[image: Configuration Window of an histogram]

And then you can click over the `i` icon in the right corner of the histogram.

[image: Histogram graph]

And then the raw query will appear.

[image: Raw query]

I am using Kibana 3 milestone 4, but this feature was available in previous releases.

And at least for now, you can not edit the queries that Kibana does. I also do not understand why do you want to do that. There is some way to parameterize things with URL parameters, but I do not think that it is what you are asking in this question.

Comment: @ipolevoy can you post your solution please.

Comment: @Nate, just noticed your comment. each widget has a configure icon in the right upper corner. Click that, and then select Inspect check box save changes. This will display a inspect icon next to configure icon, also in the right upper corner. Click that Inspect icon,  you will see the raw JSON query

Comment: That feature is very often required without reply: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/814